# Reproduzir vídeo armazenado na web python

Tags: python, tkinter

Imagina que eu tenho vídeo em um diretório de um site e não em uma tag , exemplo: www.site.com/video.mp4, tem como eu reproduzir esse video usando python + tkinter ?

Answer (score 1):

Em python, voce pode reproduzir videos com a [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/). Nunca utilizei para reproduzir videos armazenados remotamente, mas se vc puder, é só baixar o video (dentro da própria app) para o local da aplicação e executá-lo, abaixo um exemplo da [documentação](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html):

```
# Playing Video from file 

import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Se o video estiver em um serviço na rede, temos a [livestreamer](http://docs.livestreamer.io/) que é uma lib (CLI) que permite a captura de streams de serviços como youtube, dailymotion, etc, e vc pode executar em um player do tipo VLC ou desenvolvido por vc.

Comment: Não, minha resposta é para vc reproduzir videos via python, como tkinter é nativo do python basta vc fazer a adaptacao necessaria.

Comment: Talvez caiba uma nova pergunta depois da minha resposta: "Como usar OpenCV com Tkinter?" Mas isso não invalida minha resposta, muito pelo contrário, não é?

Comment: Aliás, tem até uma resposta para essa pergunta ("Como usar OpenCV com Tkinter?") no STOen, [veja a resposta aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32362559/2879341)

Comment: Concorda? @nbro

Comment: Peço desculpas ao autor da pergunta @Caymmy, por ter respondido aqui nos comentários como se fosse ele o autor do comentário equivocado.